# Lots of file changes when do Git fetch remotely and then checkout

Tags: git

I have a script to do git fetch from a remote branch and then checkout. After checking out, there are many changes locally.

```
git fetch origin pull/1234/head:not_exist_yet_branch
# do something
git checkout not_exist_yet_branch
```

After that, my local is giving lots of changes with `git status`.
For example:

```
$ git status

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   abc/file1.py
        modified:   abc/file2.py
        modified:   abc/file3.py
        modified:   abc/file4.py
        modified:   abc/file5.py
```

How can I checkout and don't have to see those changes in git status?

Comment: There is really not enough information in the question for someone to be able understand what is happening and offer advice. A cut-and-paste of the actual actions and output would help.

Comment: I normally just do `git fetch` without specifying the rest of your line. Then when I checkout the branch it just does what I'd expect - creates a local branch that tracks to the remote.

Comment: I have added outputs. I know it's weird. First time I see this behaviour as well.